# How to set the style for an entire column in EPPlus?

Tags: epplus

Is it possible to set the style for an entire column in EPPlus? I would expect that I could just use the `Column` method, but when I do I get strange results:

```
//Sets all cells in all columns to Red
worksheet.Column(1).Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.Red);

//Sets some cells in column B to red.
worksheet.Column(2).Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.Red);
```

In both cases I am setting the colour after adding some header rows but before adding the bulk of the rows am an not setting the colour anywhere else. I also get similar unexpected results setting the horizontal alignment. At the moment I am resorting to having to set the style at the cell level.

Am I using it incorrectly or is this a bug? Using EPPlus 3.1.2.0 and Excel 2010 (14.0.6129.5000) .

Answer (score 13):

```
 int indexOfColumn = ...;
 worksheet.Column(indexOfColumn).Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.Red);
```

Answer (score 8):

Try using ranges; I was having a problem with using numbers as well.

```
//Get the final row for the column in the worksheet
int finalrows = worksheet.dimension.End.Row;

//Convert into a string for the range.
string ColumnString = "A1:A" + finalrows.ToString();

//Convert the range to the color Red
worksheet.Cells[ColumnString].Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.Red);
```

Hopefully this works,but I didn't try it out.

Comment: Thanks!  This helped me out!

If you're trying to skip the conversion you can also do `worksheet.Dimension.End.Address`

Comment: It is possible there's this bug in EPPLUS as I still get duplicate styles in other columns if using numbers (Excel 2016 and EPPLUS 4.5), but using range solve this issue. This should be marked as the right answer.