# How to color entire column in excel using c# in epplus?

Tags: c#, excel, header, string-matching, epplus

I have written a code which colors a single cell which matches the text in cell, but I want to color the entire column which has a matching text in the header row

```
using System.Drawing;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using OfficeOpenXml.Style;
using System.IO;
namespace Project32
{
public class Class1
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\mvmurthy\Downloads\Template.xlsx");
        ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile);
        var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets["ImportTemplate"];
        var start = ws.Dimension.Start;
        var end = ws.Dimension.End;
        for (int col = start.Column; col <= end.Column; col++)
        { // ... Cell by cell...
            if (ws.Cells[1, col].Text == "Tracking Numbers")
            {
                ws.Cells[1, col].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                ws.Cells[1, col].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Red);
            }
        }

        pck.Save();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15673296/how-to-set-the-style-for-an-entire-column-in-epplus

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
excelWorksheet.Column(i).Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
excelWorksheet.Column(i).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FF00CC"));
```