# How to hide grid lines for one column using epplus

Tags: c#, .net, epplus

```
WorkSheet.View.ShowGridLines = false;
```

This will hide gridlines in full excel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the style for an entire column in EPPlus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15673296/how-to-set-the-style-for-an-entire-column-in-epplus)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Gridlines apply to the entire worksheet only, either in the view, print, or both.  I think you are talking about `Border` settings.  You would do something like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Column_Border()
{
    var datatable = new DataTable("tblData");
    datatable.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] {
        new DataColumn("Col0", typeof(object)),
        new DataColumn("Col1", typeof(int)),
        new DataColumn("Col2", typeof(int)),
        new DataColumn("Col3", typeof(object))
    });
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var row = datatable.NewRow();
        row[0] = Path.GetRandomFileName();
        row[1] = i;
        row[2] = i * 10;
        row[3] = Path.GetRandomFileName();
        datatable.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    var fi = new FileInfo("c:\\temp\\Column_Border.xlsx");
    if (fi.Exists)
        fi.Delete();

    using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(fi))
    {
        var WorkSheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("source");
        WorkSheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(datatable, true);
        WorkSheet.View.ShowGridLines = false;

        var allCells = WorkSheet.Cells;
        allCells.Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
        allCells.Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
        allCells.Style.Border.Bottom.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
        allCells.Style.Border.Left.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
        allCells.Style.Border.Right.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;

        allCells.Style.Border.Top.Color.SetColor(Color.Green);
        allCells.Style.Border.Bottom.Color.SetColor(Color.Green);
        allCells.Style.Border.Left.Color.SetColor(Color.Green);
        allCells.Style.Border.Right.Color.SetColor(Color.Green);

        var colRange2 = WorkSheet.Column(2);
        colRange2.Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.None;
        colRange2.Style.Border.Bottom.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.None;
        colRange2.Style.Border.Left.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.None;
        colRange2.Style.Border.Right.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.None;

        pck.Save();
    }
}
```

Gives you this:

[image]